# Hide first view while current view is the last indexed view in icarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqAlS.png]

I want my carousel to be like this (as per image). When my current index will be 3 (last index), hide the first indexed View and when my current index will be 0 (first index), hide the last index. It should be cyclic, like a book .

Please help me out. I am trying this for 3 days and not getting a solution.

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel{
  [self updateCarousalAtIndex:(long)self.carousalView.currentItemIndex];
}


-(void)updateCarousalAtIndex:(NSInteger )index{

    UIView *firstCard = (UIView *)[self.carousalView itemViewAtIndex:0];
    UIView *lastCard = (UIView *)[self.carousalView itemViewAtIndex:(long)self.cardData.count-1];
     if (index == 0) {
         NSLog(@"updateCarousalAtIndex 0");

         lastCard.alpha = 0.f;
         firstCard.alpha = 1.f;

         CGRect frame = lastCard.frame;
         frame.size.width = 0.f;
         lastCard.frame = frame;
      }else{
                  NSLog(@"updateCarousalAtIndex %ld",(long)index);
          firstCard.alpha = 0.f;
         lastCard.alpha = 1.f;

          CGRect frame = firstCard.frame;
           frame.size.width = 0.f;
          firstCard.frame = frame;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Could you post any of your attempt?

Comment: @ il_raffa ,Please check

Comment: @il_raffa ,    I have answered the above question.But the by adding following code ,The array index is suffling while adding the view to carousal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the below code ,it will solve the problem of hiding back card

```
 - (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value{
    case iCarouselOptionFadeMin:
                return 0;//for hiding first card
            case iCarouselOptionFadeMax:
                return 1;
            case iCarouselOptionFadeRange:
                return 3;
           default: {
               return value;
              }

    }
```